# Windows Server 2016 blue screen "Critical Process died"

Tags: windows, bsod, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows 2016 virtual machine that blue screens during startup. I've tried `SFC /scannow` and `BCD /FixBoot`. After booting in safe mode and last known good configuration, the blue screen still occurs. After booting into the RE there's no option to reset your machine like in Windows 10 that I see. The image recovery is an actual image of your system that you had to have already made, and the 2nd option to boot to the Command Prompt is useless because I used the two commands that I know. The third option (not shown because this is after I tried booting from CD) is to reboot in safe mode which I already tried. Surely there is a way to repair Windows Server 2016 Enterprise like Windows 10 without rolling back to a virtual machine snapshot.

repair options:
[image]

Here is the Blue Screen:
[image]

This is the [small dmp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66XeQb2IQk5R0s2WlB3QVRhOGM/view?usp=sharing). Large dump is also available if someone thinks they can locate what happened.
Here is [osr analysis](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66XeQb2IQk5Y1J4aG5ZbXFWMGs/view?usp=sharing) (must select download pdf, google drive won't display the pdf for some reason).

Comment: Yes, DISM should be used on any Windows 8+ including Windows Server 2012+ but not every problem can be repaired. If the automatic repair is failing and you don’t have a recovery point, then you don’t have a great deal of options.  No, Windows Reset isn’t a feature of Windows Server.

Comment: @Ramhound, THat's a good idea. Let me see what happens

Comment: It might help to post the actual blue screen details.

Comment: @Appleoddity Done. Windows isn't much help.

Comment: @Ramhound, btw DISM (dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /RestoreHealth /Source:D:\) didn't fix it. I'm reading about how to install symbol files to read the dump file because Windows fall update occurred yesterday and I installed .NET Core 2.0 via VStudio 2017 on the same day and it could be either. Never looked at dump files before. Just reset windows and hope they don't come back.

Comment: Please post the mindump files in some public repository (OneDrive, DropBox, etc.) and provide a link for read-only access. They'e in c:\windows\minidump by default. We can at least figure out which "critical process" is dying, and if we're lucky, we can figure out why. btw there is no need to "install symbol files" - the debugger (WinDbg) will fetch them automatically from the Microsoft symbol server. You do however have to install WinDbg.

Comment: Maybe submit a minidump here: http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=Analyze

Comment: @RickBrant added the small dump. It says ntkrnlmp.exe. I'm interested to know what caused this if someone with kernel debugging knowledge wants to inspect the full dump.

Comment: @HelpingHand Done.